# opencv for windows XP

Tags: python, opencv, windows-xp

I'm working with opencv in my last study's project. I have python 2.7 x86 and opencv 3.4 already installed.
I developed my python project in windows 8 64 bit and I converted my application from .py to .exe through Pyinstaller and it's working fine .

But when I move my application to the industrial machine which is windows xp pack 3 32bit and i try to import cv2 I get the following error :

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Note that I have tried to install Microsoft visual c++ 2015 and didn't solve the problem and I try everything said about this problem on stackoverflow and didn't work with me .

Can anyone help me here ?

Comment: Can you find out that dll file isn’t found? Use Process Explorer and Process Monitor for Windows. https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You should copy opencv.dll to directory contains .exe.

Comment: I did what you said but this didn't work also even in our code .py we have the same ImportError .

Answer (score 0):

The latest supported version **opencv** for WindowsXP and with Python v3.4 support is '**3.2.0.8**'
You can still install it by following command:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.2.0.8
```